# Adding header to symfony csv serialiser

Tags: export-to-csv, symfony4

So, I have an array that is converted and saved into csv file but I can't figure out how to customise column headers.  I've followed this [documention](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#the-csvencoder)

and here is the line that converts the array to csv:

`$csv = $serializer->serialize($person, 'csv');`

Answer (score 0):

I think its impossible, when you open csv file you are asked whether first row is headers. I'm not 100% sure but pushing headers at beginning array it maybe the only solution:

```
array_unshift($person , $headers);
$csv = $serializer->serialize($person, 'csv');
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony documentation :

> the first line must be the header with the names of the columns, which will be transformed into the object properties.

**so you need to use php function as [array_unshift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)**

finaly  your code will be as :

```
$head = $SomeCoolData; 
array_unshift($person , $head);
$csv = $serializer->serialize($person, 'csv');
```